# RStudio: Disable output of a code in Source Window while writing RMarkdown Document

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, r-markdown, chunks

I recently updated my RStudio and while writing an R Markdown document in the Source Window, whenever I run a code in a chunk of the RMD, the output is shown in the source window itself in the following manner. It gets too messy when there are huge plots. Would like to disable this feature if possible and revert back to good old style of displaying output in the Console/Plot viewer window only.

[Output executed and visible below the Chunk in the Source Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yZVx.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Try this in Rstudio.

Tools > Global Options > R Markdown > **Uncheck: Show output inline for all R Markdown Documents.**

That should disable inline code chunk output when you're editing R Markdown documents.

Does that get you what you're asking?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked perfectly. This is exactly what I needed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like OP had his question answered, but if toggling "Show output line for all R Markdown Documents" has no effect, you may be dealing with the bug detailed here: [Chunk output in console not always available](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115001246268-Chunk-output-in-console-not-always-available). You'll have to uncheck that box, restart, and then select the option to "Chunk Output in Console" from the output menu before re-enabling the former setting.