# prevent r-markdown from unfolding code/function

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, folding

Here is my r-markdown code:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
```{r}

test_funciton <- function(){<->}

3+5

```
````

observe that `test_function` is folded. Now when I execute `3+5` line I end up with with the following view:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
```{r}

test_funciton <- function(){
  print('test')
}

3+5

```
````

`test_function` is now unfolded. I wonder if I can prevent this unfolding behavior?

Comment: you could put `code_folding:hide` in your `YAML` section.

Comment: @Matt thank you, I ran `> code_folding:hide` and got back 
`Error: object 'code_folding' not found`

Comment: Did you put this in your YAML after `html_output:` ?  [this link](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html) may be helpful

Comment: @Matt, Here is how my YAML section looks: `---
title: "Test"
author: "Test"
date: "11/5/2019"
output: html_document
    code_folding:hide
---`

Comment: you need `:` after `html_document`

Comment: @Matt, thank you again. Here is new format: `---
title: "Test"
output: 
    html_document:
      code_folding:hide
---` and error is `Error: object 'output' not found`. I read your link and I do not think it relates to my question. reading more...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42350815/rstudio-disable-output-of-a-code-in-source-window-while-writing-rmarkdown-docum) ?
I tried to reproduce your problem in my RStudio v1.2.5033 and it worked for me.

---

> Tools > Global Options > R Markdown > **Uncheck: Show output inline for all R Markdown Documents.**
>
> That should disable inline code chunk output when you're editing R Markdown documents.
> Does that get you what you're asking?

---

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a shot, but my question is not about output, but about code folding and unfolding.

Comment: I know it seems deccorelated, but unckecking this option made me get in my IDE the expected behaviour that you describe.

Comment: I mean, I selected only `3+5` inside the chunk, ran it, and the function dit not unfold.

Comment: This doesn't work. The code will still unfold.

Comment: If you are willing to view output in the console instead of previewing in R Markdown, this option seems to work, at least for me.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are still having this issue, maybe changing where the '}' is located at the bottom of your unfolded function may help.
Instead of:

f <- function(a){
k <- sqrt(a)
return(k)
**}**

Try:
f <- function(a){
k <- sqrt(a)
return(k)
**}**

It worked for me.